# How intent object keep/transfer data between two Activity in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i have these two Activity and each in the separate file:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
        public void sendMessage(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

       Intent intent = getIntent();
       String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
       TextView textView = new TextView(this);
       textView.setTextSize(40);
       textView.setText(message);

       ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_message);
       layout.addView(textView);
    }
    }
```

in MainActivity we create `Intent` object and hold him some data ,
in the `DisplayMessageActivity` we get this intent using `getIntent()` method ,
and this method return to us `Intent` object 
my question is how this method return to us the same Intent that we create in `MainActivity` ??

Comment: Do you want to know how Android handles Intents internally?
Then I'd encourage you to have a deep look into the Android source code.

Comment: i just need high level knowledge about this technical , i do not want to Dive in many codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to official documentation, get intent is used to

> Return the intent that started this activity.

It means it is a function that returns the intent that originally started that activity. 
That answers your query.

[Android Developers Documentation - Activity - getIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent())

It is always a good practice to read official documentation.

The general syntax to add extras is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, activity.class); //Create intent to start activity
intent.putExtra("key", data); //adding data
startActivity(intent);
```

To receive that data, from the Activity you started:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String data = intent.getExtra("key");
```

The String variable - data will hold the value that you attached with the previous activity. This means, you can only use this method till the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `onActivityResult` in you MainActivity and start DisplayMessageActivity with `startActivityForResult`:

```
... sendMessage(View view) {
    ...
    startActivityForResult(intent, MESSAGE_RESULT_CODE);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data) {
    //You can get your result intent data here
    if (requestcode == MESSAGE_RESULT_CODE && resultcode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

and just add in DisplayMessageActivity in `onPause`, `onStop` or `onBackPressed` and `onSupportNavigateUp`:

```
//in your case maybe 'your_intent_sent_back_to_mainactivity = getIntent();'
setResult(RESULT_OK, your_intent_sent_back_to_mainactivity);
```

**ADDITIONALLY**

The source in Android Developer Community:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: sorry you don't understand my question , in need to know how getIntent() return the same object that i created before ,not new Intent object ?

Comment: Then you call (in DisplayMessageActivity)  `setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());` This will return the Intent sent to DisplayMessageActivity to MainActivity. Same content. If it is really the same object or just a copy is above my knowledge.